# How to visualize heapdump?

Tags: debugging, go, garbage-collection, heap-dump

We have developed a server using golang which will receive concurrent request and process the request(creates big object - a tree) and then send back reply. But the objects are not garbage collected. So I decided to analyze the objects that live in the memory. To start with, I wrote a simple program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    var i_am_a int = 10
    _ = i_am_a
    func() {
        f, err := os.Create("dump")
        defer f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        debug.WriteHeapDump(f.Fd())
    }()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("dump")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(b))

}
```

But I couldn't understand the representaion(https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/heapdump13 - this didn't help). All I wanted is to trace back from the memory(big object) to the place(variable in go app code) which holds the root address of the object. So that I can release the reference and let GC to collect it in it's cycle. Is there a latest tool to visualize heapdump? or Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Could this link help you in your Go memory analysis? https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs

Comment: @JeandeyBoris, I have already tried those tricks. But, none of them actually helps. Only information that will help is Heap Dump which I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 3):

There is, currently, no complete solution to your problem. The [newest heap dump format](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/heapdump15) explains that some information previously available is no longer tracked by the runtime.

[Go Issue 16410](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16410) has lots of details and information on work in progress.

One tool - a work in progress - that may help is [goheapdump](https://github.com/tombergan/goheapdump)

Answer (score -4):

You can use `net/pprof` package. Just follow the steps in https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs to dump heap/cpu profile.

And you can use `go tool pprof binary dumpfile` to analyse a dumpfile. Type `web` in the interactive analysis tool, you can see the call graph in your web browser.

Comment: Can you explain how profiling will help me to find the object which are not garbage collected?

Comment: @Spartan Wasn't the original question is to look at the heapdump? Since you've already be able to visualize the heap, you can find out what is exactly in taking the heap space. And usually the objects in the heap taking lots of spaces is considered not garbage collected, which gives you the way to find out whether it's due to cycle reference or not.