# Is there a way to know who holds a reference to an object in Go?

Tags: debugging, go, memory-leaks

I am currently trying to debug a nasty memory leak in [our Go code](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/pull/1173).

What I know:

- where memory is going (`pprof` with `-base` flag)
- why new memory is being allocated ("reconnect" feature in our code)
- number of goroutines is not growing (`runtime.NumGoroutine()`)
- if I do `object = nil`, memory will be garbage collected (good! but now I have data races with other go-routines that are using this object)

What I don't know:

- why new memory is not being garbage collected. for that I need to know who holds a reference(s) to an object.

Thank you for your time and any advice!

Comment: `pprof` can diff heap profiles and show you objects or space allocated. This should be enough to tell you which objects hold the memory. From there, it shouldn't be too difficult to know what actually holds references (just audit your code). Also, make sure it's being held, otherwise it could be a case of memory being GCed, but not released to the OS. Other than that, no way to do it though you could create a wrapper around the object with an explicit `TakeOwnership("new owner")` method.

Comment: thanks @Marc! I did took advantage of the `-base` flag. but it's still difficult to pin the exact place. "but not released to the OS" how do I check that? And how does that knowledge help me exactly? Process still going to crash eventually. TakeOwnership smells like Rust :)

Comment: Also, I've added one more point about memory deallocated when I do `object = nil`.

Comment: Ok, then it definitely sounds like references still being held. `TakeOwnership` is if you have a type only your code uses, then you can annotate what is using it, it's purely a debugging thing. It won't work if you need to pass it to other libraries. We can't really help you though, you haven't even shown what is still being held. If is a buffer, a large object, a channel? In general, it sounds like something is not calling `close()`, gut that's just a wild guess on my part.

Comment: @melekes: It's vary hard to leak memory in Go without also leaking goroutines. If the number of goroutines isn't increasing, then the next place to look is that NewTicker call referenced in the linked issue. Have you verified how many tickers are created and that `Stop` is called on all the unused ones? (there's a lot of tickers created by that code in general, discarding them without stopping them is a surefire way to leak memory). Short of that, you haven't really provided any specific data to look at here, or a way to replicate the issue.

Comment: Ok. I think I found who's holding a reference to the object. This was a test-case. In production however, the number of go-routines was indeed increasing. Thanks @JimB for your help! Should I close this question?

Comment: @melekes: as I suspected ;) My first response to a memory leak is always to look at a stack trace. I would go ahead and close it, since there's no content here to help anyone else.

Comment: voted for closing. for anybody who's interested, here is the article with tips and whole story https://blog.cosmos.network/debugging-the-memory-leak-in-tendermint-210186711420

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to visualize heapdump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542775/how-to-visualize-heapdump)

Comment: This reminded me of a talk I saw on YouTube not to long ago. GoRoutines (and the GC system) are scheduled cooperatively. If your code doesn’t do any io, you may be stuck busily computing in a goroutine without allowing go to run GC. Doing the equivalent of a sleep(0) periodically should help if it it a starvation issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two tools.

Use [Go Guru](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Y9xCEMj5S-7rv2ooHpZNH15JgRT5iM742gJkw5LtmQ/edit), to see who pointsto or referrers to a pointer.  It is integrated with the [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) plugin I use, I did a post on that [here](https://www.pavedroad.io/part-3-vim-go-plugin/).

[Valgrind](https://www.cossacklabs.com/blog/investigating-go-memory-leaks.html) is a tool for C/C++ but found an article about using it with Go.

Comment: I think you might be mixing vagrant with vargrind?

Answer (score -2):

Your code is 404 not found.

When you put object = nil. this did not be cleared immediately however when some goroutine still holds it , the object will keep still even if gc runs.

You ask who hold the reference, goroutine who uses this val without put it to nil or the goroutine uses it in a loop will both keep the reference.

The gc() will never marked a referred reference to black, then it will never be clear

Comment: @melekes Indeed it's not (on github). It might be a comment about how the code isn't part of your question, which is what is expected of a question here. Being a bit acquainted with the tendermint code, I do understand it's kind of a tricky thing to post a minimal code sample to explain the extent of the problem without posting a couple of thousand lines though..