# How to analize which object owns the max memory

Tags: go, memory, coredump, memory-profiling, pprof

The Go program contains large memory and I want to know which objects own the max memory.

1. I have try pprof, but it can only show where alloc memory.
2. There is heap dump function, but I can not find any core dump reader

https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#WriteHeapDump

For example, like the top consumers MAT for java

[image]

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542775/how-to-visualize-heapdump